# Fast Switch between CoffeeScript and JavaScript Files in VIM

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, vim

sadly I´m new to Vimscript and failed to write a function which switches from a `.coffee` file to the corresponding `.js` file.

I wonder if anyone already has done this?

I know there is the function `:CoffeeCompile watch` of the vim-coffee-script plugin but the file you see there is not the real you’ve stored locally.

It would be cool to have a function like this (if you store your `.coffee` and `.js` files in the same directory):

```
function! GoToJS()
  " get current file path in a string variable
  " change the .coffee extention to a .js extention
  " open the .js file
endfunction
```

Something like this would be really cool-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the vim plugin [`a.vim`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/a.vim). It's configurable. Add those to `.vimrc`:

```
let g:alternateExtensions_coffee = 'js'
let g:alternateExtensions_js = 'coffee'
```

Comment: vim-coffee-script now has :CoffeeWatch that works very nicely (albeit not quite what the OP asked for since it isn't viewing the actual output file). See http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-coffee-script for more details.

Comment: I just found this response, and also used the g:alternateSearchPath regex to find all my api coffee files in backend, and all my web coffee files in frontend (which are the destinations from my gulp build, so you can change to fit) thusly: `let g:alternateSearchPath =  'reg:#/api#/backend#,reg:#/web#/frontend/scripts#'`

Answer (score 0):

I love to cheat with coffeescript while coding native javascript on linux.
Here's how I swap between pretty easily:

- run this once `npm install -g js2coffee coffee-script`
- put this in your `vimrc`:

.

```
  nmap cc :! [[ \! -f %:r.coffee ]] && js2coffee % > %:r.coffee<CR>:sp %:r.coffee<CR>
```

- open a **.js**-file, and create/switch-to the `.coffee`-file by typing: `cc`

see more nifty shortcuts in this article: [switch-coffeescript-and-javascript-in-vim-like-a-ninja](http://leon.vankammen.eu/tech/switch-coffeescript-and-javascript-in-vim-like-a-ninja.html)